# Getting a getXMLHTTP is not defined error

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getState(countryId)
{
   var strURL="findState.php?country="+countryId;
   var req = getXMLHTTP();
     //ERROR is right here
     //UNCAUGHT REFERENCE ERROR: getXMLHTTP IS NOT DEFINED
   if (req)
   {
     req.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
      if (req.readyState == 4)
      {
      // only if "OK"
     if (req.status == 200)
         {
        document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
     } else {
       alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
     }
        }
      }
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
   }
}
</script>
```

It is being called from this:

```
  <tr>
   <td width="150">Country</td>
   <td width="150"><select style="background-color: #ffffa0" name="country" onchange="getState(this.value)"><option>Select Country</option><option value="1">USA</option><option value="2">Canada</option>       </select></td>
  </tr>
```

Just to be safe, this is my header, maybe I am doing this incorrectly?

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view/css/application.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="view/javascript/application.js" ></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Another note, I am working off [this](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html) example and he is using a mysql server, I am using ODBC to connect to an Access database. Would I not use xmlHTTP for this? I honestly don't know.

Comment: what is application.js? if it is your jQuery code include it after jQuery otherwise error will be thrown

Comment: It is my jQuery code. When you say include it after the jQuery you mean after the 

<script src="//ajax.... line?

Comment: yes, that would be better practice, because (of course that depends on your code structure) code likely will not works properly in that case

Comment: I appreciate the tip but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Could my application.js file simply not have getXMLHTTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getXMLHTTP() should look like this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function getXMLHTTP() {
           var x = false;
           try {
              x = new XMLHttpRequest();
           }catch(e) {
             try {
                x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }catch(ex) {
                try {
                    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e1) {
                    x = false;
                }
             }
          }
          return x;
        }

        function getState(countryId){
          var strURL="findState.php?country="+countryId;
          var req = getXMLHTTP();

          if (req){
            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
              if (req.readyState == 4){
                if (req.status == 200){
                  document.getElementById('statediv').innerHTML=req.responseText;
                } else {
                  alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
              }
            }
            req.open("GET", strURL, true);
            req.send(null);
           }
        }
</script>
```